# Inheriting __iadd__ From date, and Return Instance of New Class

Tags: python, oop

I have a few jobs that need to run slightly differently on the last Friday of each month. So I want to add a method IsLastFriday to date, that returns `True` if the date being looked at is the last Friday of the month. So I've written my own class that inherits from date, and adds that logic.

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

class my_date(date):

    def __init__(self, y, m ,d):
        super(my_date, self).__init__(y, m, d)

    def IsLastFriday(self):
        days = [0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31]
        month = self.month
        total_days = days[month]
        if total_days - self.day <= 6 and self.isoweekday == 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        n_date = self.__add__(other)
        n_my_date = my_date(n_date.year, n_date.month, n_date.day)
        return n_my_date
```

Which all works fine. I feel that there really should be a more elegant/efficient way to implement `__iadd__`, instead of constructing a new object each time.

When I try to call

```
super(my_date, self).__iadd__(other)
```

I get an error because `'super' object has no attribute '__iadd__'`, and if I try to call `__add__` I get an instance of date back.

I feel like I should be able to inherit `__iadd__` somehow, because it's callable for date objects.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like I should be able to inherit `__iadd__` somehow, because it's callable for date objects.

It's not. `date` objects don't have `__iadd__`;  when you try to use `+=` on them, Python looks for `__iadd__`, finds it's not there, and uses `__add__` instead. Since `date` objects are immutable, there's no way to implement `__iadd__` in a mutative manner, so you shouldn't actually be implementing `__iadd__` at all; you should implement `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing built-in types is not the way to go if you just want to add some logic that operates on a `datetime` instance. A simple function would do just fine:

```
import datetime

def is_last_friday_of_month(dt):
    """Determine whether `dt` is the last Friday of the month."""
    if dt.weekday() != 4:  # Friday is 4
        return False
    dt_week_after = dt + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
    return dt.month != dt_week_after.month
```

Use it like this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if is_last_friday_of_month(dt):
    print("It's the last Friday of the month.")
```